# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing std::vector as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, parameters, glm-math

I have a function called *calculateMaxPoint()* which goes through an array of vec3s to determine the maximum x, y and z values. It is used across my file multiple different time, so that it is able to go through many different arrays.

It doesn't work though. I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception at runtime when the function is called. I've tried making the parameter into a pointer, and more recently I've tried using the `const` declaration. Neither worked.

```
    glm::vec3 calculateMaxPoint(std::vector<glm::vec3> & points) {
    float max[3] = {points[0].x, points[0].y, points[0].z};

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        if (points[i].x > max[0])
            max[0] = points[i].x;

        if (points[i].y > max[1])
            max[1] = points[i].y;

        if (points[i].z > max[2])
            max[2] = points[i].z;
    }

    return glm::vec3(max[0], max[1], max[2]);
    }
```

If any info is needed, let me know.

Comment: What is `vertices`? Or is it just a typo and the parameter name is `vertices` not `points`? In your code, if `points` is empty you will get an exception when accessing `points[0]`, you should check if it is not empty before that.

Comment: It was a typo! I'll check it now.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis how do I check if it's empty? And if it is, how do I fix that?

Comment: I added an answer on how to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can judge from your code, the issue could arise if the vector `points` that is passed as an argument is empty (contains no elements). In that case referencing the element with index zero that you are doing on the first line is invalid. What you should do is add a line that checks if the vector is empty and handle that scenario. The snippet below returns a vector with all zero values:

```
if (points.size() == 0)
{
    // In this example return a vector with 0 values
    return glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

You can modify this code as to your needs - return a vector with different values or possibly throw and exception.

Comment: But the only times when I pass a `std::vector<glm::vec3>` *is* when it is full of something …

Comment: Wait, this is the answer. Coursework makes me irksome. Thank you very much!